# write parquet files with defined column name instead of using dataframe's column name

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, parquet

I am very much new to scala and not sure how can dig into this.
I have a dataframe with many columns as below :

```
+---+-----+--------+--------+
| _1|_2._1|_2._2._1|_2._2._2|
+---+-----+--------+--------+
|  1|    2|       3|       4|
+---+-----+--------+--------+
```

and i write it into parquet but i have already a schema including the column names that will be in parquert as below:

```
  val abcSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("ModID", StringType),
    StructField("ProGroupId", StringType),
    StructField("ProdId", StringType),
    StructField("SegId", StringType),
    StructField("Date", DateType),
    StructField("MShare", DoubleType),
    StructField("MtId", IntegerType),
    StructField("Flag", BooleanType),
    StructField("ProType", StringType),
    StructField("abc", StringType),
    StructField("xyz", StringType),
    StructField("ghi", DoubleType),
    StructField("jkl", DoubleType),
    StructField("mno", DoubleType),
    StructField("pqr", DoubleType),
    StructField("stu", DoubleType),
    StructField("wxy", DoubleType),
    StructField("zyw", DoubleType),
    StructField("pou", DoubleType),
    StructField("hyt", DoubleType),
    StructField("kpol", DoubleType),
    StructField("uyt", DoubleType),
    StructField("qwre", DoubleType),
    StructField("jgt", DoubleType),
    StructField("lpou", DoubleType),
    StructField("qret", DoubleType),
    StructField("cvd", DoubleType),
    StructField("bnhy", DoubleType),
    StructField("nnn", DoubleType),
    StructField("loi", DoubleType),
    StructField("kql", DoubleType)
  ))
```

The final result of parquet file should be like this

```
+------+----------+--------+--------+
| ModID|ProGroupId|ProdId  |abc     |
+------+----------+--------+--------+
|  1   |    2     |       3|       4|
+------+----------+--------+--------+
```

I have written the below code to create parquet using the code

```
val result = Try({

      dataFrame
        .write
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .format("parquet")
        .partitionBy("Date")
        .save(outputPath)
    })
```

However,I am not sure ,How can i pass the "abcSchema" into the above code to write the parquet with required columns.
Can anyone please help me??

Answer (score 0):

Load the schema while reading dataframe itself and then write.

```
spark.read.format("<format>")
     .option("<key>", "<value>")
     .schema(abcSchema)
     .load("<path-to-file>")
```